# Getting error 'gtk_window_set_keep_above' undeclared while compiling code on 32 bit linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, gtk, redhat

Same C/C++ code was compiling successfully on 64-bit, while compiling on 32-bit machine (after updating makefile changes etc) it is giving following error:

```
**'gtk_window_set_keep_above' undeclared**
```

while checking headers for gtk, it was found that header file `gtkwindows.h` does not have this function causing the error.

Now my question is which GTK+ package to update for `gtk2-devel` package without impacting other packages?

Currently installed `gtk2-devel` package is `gtk2-devel-2.2.4-1`.

System Information: Linux Red Hat 3 (Taroon update 4).

Answer (score 1):

A [quick look in the docs](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/GtkWindow.html#gtk-window-set-keep-above) would have told you the answer:

> > Since 2.4

So, you need at least GTK+ 2.4.0.